# Error in ZODB backup

Tags: python, zodb

I have indico 0.92 and we backup it with ZODB.

This program run a lot of time suddenly the backup stop working with the errors:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "ZODB.FileStorage"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/.../ZODB3-3.4.2/build/scripts-2.4/repozo.py", line 517, in ?
    main()
  File "/usr/local/.../ZODB3-3.4.2/build/scripts-2.4/repozo.py", line 510, in main
    do_backup(options)
  File "/usr/local/.../ZODB3-3.4.2/build/scripts-2.4/repozo.py", line 478, in do_backup
    do_incremental_backup(options, reposz, repofiles)
  File "/usr/local/.../ZODB3-3.4.2/build/scripts-2.4/repozo.py", line 378, in do_incremental_backup
    fs = FileStorage(options.file, read_only=True)
  File "build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 163, in __init__
  File "build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 1697, in read_index
  File "build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.4/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 52, in panic
ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage.CorruptedTransactionError: %s has invalid transaction header at %s
```

Any idea what can cause the ZODB backup to stop working?

Shlomit

Comment: Your ZODB filestorage is corrupted; it could be as simple as one corrupted transaction header, or there could be more endemic damage. Since you already have a Repozo backup, just restore from your most recent backup.

Answer (score 0):

I dont familiar with ZODB much.

I dont have a backup for a few days now and I'm afraid that if I restore it from my last backup users will lost data. Is the 'ZODB filestorage' is general files and not connect to the users data?

As I said, I dont familiar with that can you give more detail how can I do it safety? I dont want to mess things.

Thanks a lot,

Shlomit

Comment: finally we run fsrecover.py on data and the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd put some information here for any weary travellers from the future. If you are seeing the above error, then the Data.fs file is corrupted. From what I can tell, your only way to get zope to start again is to run fsrecover.py over it:
https://github.com/zopefoundation/ZODB/blob/master/src/ZODB/fsrecover.py

The above file will essentially just delete any corrupted data, but at least you'll be back up and running.

Good luck!